# Passing/storing a value to another function or click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently in the middle of building a slider for my project. I've managed to build the controls and looking to create and looking to incorporate the directional arrows.

My current problem is the directional arrows, how can I pass the `index` value from the control to the directional controls so that it knows what slide is currently on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


 var programSliderWidth = $('.program-slider').width(),
     sliderContainer    = $('.program-slider .slides'),
     slides             = $('.program-slider .slides li'),
     move               = 0,
     position           = 0,
     totalSlides        = $('.program-slider .slides li').length;  


    //Apply width based on the width of the .program-slider
 slides.width(programSliderWidth);

 //Apply Maximum width based on number of slides
 sliderContainer.width(totalSlides * programSliderWidth);

    //Slider Controls
 $('.navigation .controls li').on('click', function() {
     var position = $(this).index();
     var move     = position*programSliderWidth;

     $('.program-slider .slides').css({'right': move});
 
 });

 //Slider Directional Controls
 $('.buttons .prev').on('click', function() {
     if( position >= 0 ) {
         position--;
         $('.program-slider .slides').css({'right': - (position*programSliderWidth) });
         
     }
 });

 $('.buttons .next').on('click', function() {
  if( position <= totalSlides ) {
       position++;
         $('.program-slider .slides').css({'right': position * programSliderWidth});  
     }
 });
})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.program-slider {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: beige;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .program-slider .slides {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear; }
    .program-slider .slides li {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear; }

.navigation {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  .navigation .controls li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="program-slider">
   <ul class="slides">
       <li>Slide 1</li>
       <li>Slide 2</li>
       <li>Slide 3</li>
       <li>Slide 4</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="controls">
        <li>Control slide 1</li>
        <li>slide 2</li>
        <li>slide 3</li>
        <li>slide 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <ul>
        <li class="prev">Prev</li>
        <li class="next">Next</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple mistakes:

1. You are *overriding* your "global" `position` with a `var position`, in your sliders control. Just change `var position` to `position` to use the common variable, and it should work properly.
2. When you're checking if the `position` variable is out of bounds with `position >= 0` or `position <= totalSlides`, you may end with values like `-1` or `totalSlides + 1`, which are out of bounds. Instead, change those `>= 0` and `<= totalSlides` with `> 0` and `< totalSlides - 1`.
3. In your *previous* button handler, you're setting the slider position with a **negative value**. Since you're **change its position** instead of **moving it a distance**, you need to set it as a positive value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var programSliderWidth = $('.program-slider').width(),
        sliderContainer    = $('.program-slider .slides'),
        slides             = $('.program-slider .slides li'),
        move               = 0,
        position           = 0,
        totalSlides        = $('.program-slider .slides li').length;  


    //Apply width based on the width of the .program-slider
    slides.width(programSliderWidth);

    //Apply Maximum width based on number of slides
    sliderContainer.width(totalSlides * programSliderWidth);

    //Slider Controls
    $('.navigation .controls li').on('click', function() {
        position = $(this).index(); // -- CHANGE 1 --
        var move     = position*programSliderWidth;

        $('.program-slider .slides').css({'right': move});
    
    });

    //Slider Directional Controls
    $('.buttons .prev').on('click', function() {
        if( position > 0 ) { // -- CHANGE 2 --
            position--;
            $('.program-slider .slides').css({'right': position * programSliderWidth }); // -- CHANGE 3 --
        }
    });

    $('.buttons .next').on('click', function() {
        if( position < totalSlides - 1 ) { // -- CHANGE 2 --
             position++;
              $('.program-slider .slides').css({'right': position * programSliderWidth});    
          }
    });
})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.program-slider {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: beige;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .program-slider .slides {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear; }
    .program-slider .slides li {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear; }

.navigation {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  .navigation .controls li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="program-slider">
   <ul class="slides">
       <li>Slide 1</li>
       <li>Slide 2</li>
       <li>Slide 3</li>
       <li>Slide 4</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="controls">
        <li>Control slide 1</li>
        <li>slide 2</li>
        <li>slide 3</li>
        <li>slide 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <ul>
        <li class="prev">Prev</li>
        <li class="next">Next</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```